# celery_tasktree does not support DAG workflow in general. Is there an alternative?

Tags: celery, workflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

celery_tasktree (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/celery-tasktree) provides a cleaner workflow canvas compared to celery workflow scheduler (http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html). However, it only support tree-like workflow structure, not a general DAG-like workflow. Celery workflow does have "chords" method but seems cumbersome to use.

Is there any other celery-based library similar to celery_tasktree that works with general DAG workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are couple of libraries that support DAG based job schedulers.

https://github.com/thieman/dagobah

https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow

They are not based on celery. However you can create your own primitives in celery to forward results which can used to build a DAG job schedulers.

```
@app.task(bind=True)
def forward(self, result, sig):
    # convert JSON serialized signature back to Signature
    sig = self.app.signature(sig)
    # get the return value of the provided task signature
    result2 = sig()
    # next task will receive tuple of (result_A, result_B)
    return (result, result2)


@app.task
def C(self, Ares_Bres)):
    Ares, Bres = Ares__Bres
    return Ares + Bres

workflow = (A.s() | forward.s(B.s()) | C.s())
```

[See here](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3666) for a more detailed discussion.